# Cannot connect to remote repository on Bonobo Windows Server 2012

Tags: git, bonobo

I successfully installed Bonobo on my Windows 2012 server without any problem. I created a repo through the web interface, but when trying to add the remote repo through Git I get the following error:

> fatal: https://app.mydomain.com/Bonobo.Git.Server/project1.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Here is what the Bonobo Error logs show in Bonobo.Git.Server.Errors.log:

> Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Error occured and caught in Global.asax - System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
>      at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
>      at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>      at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>      at Bonobo.Git.Server.GitAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TState](AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
>   Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"...

I am using the default forms authentication. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference is incorrect. Add the remote from the command line as follows:

```
git remote add origin https://app.mydomain.com/Bonobo.Git.Server/project1.git
```

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that. I just copied the link directly from the repository page.